# Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\cas_pre_enrollment_scheduler_system\sort_subject.php on line 51

Tags: php, mysql

please help how to solve this problem need for thesis thank you

> Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\cas_pre_enrollment_scheduler_system\sort_subject.php on line 51

Code -

```
if (isset($_POST['sort'])) {
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $term = $_POST['term'];

    $courses = mysql_query("select * from course where code = '$course' LIMIT 1 ")or die(mysql_error());
    $course_id = mysql_fetch_array($courses)['course_id'];

    $user_query = mysql_query("select * from subject where course_id = $course_id and term = '$term' and year = '$year' ")or die(mysql_error());

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($user_query)) {
        //$id=$row1['subject_id']; 
        //$course_id=$row1['course_id']; 

        $course_query = mysql_query("select * from course where course_id = $course_id ")or die(mysql_error());
        $course_row = mysql_fetch_array($course_query);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Which is line 51? Also, the while and if are both missing their } close brackets.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: I would guess this line `$course_id = mysql_fetch_array($courses)['course_id'];` and its use of `['course_id']` is not supported on your version of PHP

Comment: A thesis and you are using the `mysql_` database extension??

Comment: $course_id = mysql_fetch_array($courses)['course_id'];

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code, any one of which could solve your problem

- while and if loop is not closed
- change this code as it might not be supported

  $course_id = mysql_fetch_array($courses)['course_id'];
- single quotes are missing for `$course_id` in your select queries

  I have made the changes below.Try this

  ```
   if (isset($_POST['sort']))
      {
      $year = $_POST['year'];
      $term = $_POST['term'];

      $courses = mysql_query("select * from course where code = '$course' LIMIT 1 ")or die(mysql_error());
      $rw = mysql_fetch_array($courses);
  if($rw)
  {
      $course_id = $rw['course_id'];
  }
      //single quotes for $course_id
      $user_query = mysql_query("select * from subject where course_id = '$course_id' and term = '$term' and year = '$year' ")or die(mysql_error());

      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($user_query))
      {
          //$id=$row1['subject_id']; 
          //$course_id=$row1['course_id']; 
      //single quotes for $course_id
          $course_query = mysql_query("select * from course where course_id = '$course_id' ")or die(mysql_error());
          $course_row = mysql_fetch_array($course_query);
      }
   }
  ?>
  ```

I suggest you to use `mysqli` or `PDO` database extensions further..